How to control the start and end of arrows
I would like to fix the following plot:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    reader/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=#1, minimum width=4mm, minimum height=14mm}
    ]
    
    % \draw[help lines, gray!30] (-12,-7) grid (7,7);
    \pgfmathsetseed{13} % Set the seed for reproducibility

    % 
    \def\radius{2.6}
    \def\angleIncrement{360/5.6}

    % 
    \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (-8.5,0);
    % 
    \node[reader=blue!30] (R1) at (R) {};
    \node[above] at (R1.north) {{Reader}};
    
    \draw[fill=none] (0,0) circle (\radius);
    

    \foreach \i/\label in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C, 4/D, 5/E} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{\angleIncrement * (\i + 1)}
        \coordinate (\label) at ($(center) + (\angle:\radius)$);
        \node[ rectangle,draw=black, fill=green!30, minimum width=2pt, minimum height=20pt, 
                    rotate={5 + 10*rand}, scale=0.75] at (\label) {\label};
    }

    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (B.north) -- (A.south);
    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (A.east) -- (E.west);
    \draw[latex-latex, , draw=blue, line width=0.5mm] (E.west) -- (D.east) node[pos=0.7, above left, ] {\large{$d_{DE}$}};
    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (D.east) -- (C.west);
    
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (B.west) node[pos=0.6, above, ] {\large{$d_{2}$}};
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (C.west) node[midway, above, ] (D3) {};
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (A.west) node[pos=0.7, above, ] (D1) {\large{$d_{1}$}};
    
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (E.west) node[midway, above, ] (D4) {\large{$d_{4}$}};
    \path[] (D1) -- (D3) node[pos=0.85, scale=1.3] {$\vdots$};
    
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


For example, dashed arrows d1, d2, d4 I would like to end at west of nodes A, B, and E.
Also, connecting lines A-B, A-E, C-D, and double arrow D-E.
All lines uses the center of the node to start/end. For example, B-A should go from B.north to A.south.

I know now what is doing. I am using the node on the circle but not the A, B, to E nodes to tell them the position of nodes. I will post my solution.

There's no need to define a coordinate;
\coordinate (\label) at ($(center) + (\angle:\radius)$);
\node[ rectangle,draw=black, fill=green!30, minimum width=2pt, 
 minimum height=20pt,rotate={5 + 10*rand}, scale=0.75] at (\label) {\label};

it's simpler to define node, as the arrows between nodes go from edge to edge and not to the center.
\node[ rectangle,draw=black, fill=green!30, minimum width=2pt, 
minimum height=20pt,rotate={5 + 10*rand}, scale=0.75]
at ($(center) + (\angle:\radius)$) (\label){\label};

By the way, Tikz coordinates are zero-dimensional nodes.
So to draw arrows between nodes, there's no need to specify whether they start from north, south, east or another anchor.
\draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (N2.north) -- (N1.south); 

simply write :
\draw[-,draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (N2) -- (N1);

Complete code
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    reader/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=#1, minimum width=4mm, minimum height=14mm}
    ]
    
    % \draw[help lines, gray!30] (-12,-7) grid (7,7);
    \pgfmathsetseed{13} % Set the seed for reproducibility

    % 
    \def\radius{2.6}
    \def\angleIncrement{360/5.6}

    % 
    \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (-8.5,0);
    % 
    \node[reader=blue!30] (R1) at (R) {};
    \node[above] at (R1.north) {{Reader}};
    
    \draw[fill=none] (0,0) circle (\radius);
    

    \foreach \i/\label in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C, 4/D, 5/E} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{\angleIncrement * (\i + 1)}
       \node[ rectangle,draw=black, fill=green!30, minimum width=2pt, minimum height=20pt, 
                    rotate={5 + 10*rand}, scale=0.75] at ($(center) + (\angle:\radius)$) (\label){\label};
    }

    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (B) -- (A);
    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (A) -- (E);
    \draw[latex-latex, , draw=blue, line width=0.5mm] (E) -- (D) node[pos=0.7, above left, ] {\large{$d_{DE}$}};
    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (D) -- (C);
    
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1) -- (B) node[pos=0.6, above, ] {\large{$d_{2}$}};
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1) -- (C) node[midway, above, ] (D3) {};
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1) -- (A) node[pos=0.7, above, ] (D1) {\large{$d_{1}$}};
    
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1) -- (E) node[midway, above, ] (D4) {\large{$d_{4}$}};
    \path[] (D1) -- (D3) node[pos=0.85, scale=1.3] {$\vdots$};
    

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



A solution is not to use nodes on the circle (as it doing the initial plot) of the arrows/lines and use instead nodes A,B, C, D and E.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    reader/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=#1, minimum width=4mm, minimum height=14mm}
    ]
    % Help lines
    % \draw[help lines, gray!30] (-12,-7) grid (7,7);
    \pgfmathsetseed{13} % Set the seed for reproducibility

    % Define the circle parameters
    \def\radius{2.6}
    \def\angleIncrement{360/5.6}

    % Define the center of the circle
    \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (-8.5,0);
    % Define the reader node
    \node[reader=blue!30] (R1) at (R) {};
    \node[above] at (R1.north) {{Reader}};
    
    \draw[fill=none] (0,0) circle (\radius);
    
    \foreach \i/\label in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C, 4/D, 5/E} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{\angleIncrement * (\i + 1)}
        \coordinate (\label) at ($(center) + (\angle:\radius)$);
    }
    
    % Place the nodes around the circle
    \foreach \i/\label in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C, 4/D, 5/E} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{\angleIncrement * (\i + 1)}
        \coordinate (\label) at ($(center) + (\angle:\radius)$);
        \node[ rectangle,draw=black, fill=green!30, minimum width=2pt, minimum height=20pt, 
                    rotate={5 + 10*rand}, scale=0.75] (N\i) at (\label) {\label};
    }

    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (N2.north) -- (N1.south);
    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (N1.east) -- (N5.west);
    \draw[latex-latex, , draw=blue, line width=0.5mm] (N5.south) -- (N4.north) node[pos=0.7, above left, ] {\large{$d_{DE}$}};
    \draw[-, , draw=red, line width=0.5mm] (N4.west) -- (N3.east);
    
    % Draw connections
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (N2.west) node[pos=0.6, above, ] {\large{$d_{2}$}};
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (N3.west) node[midway, above, ] (D3) {};
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (N1.west) node[pos=0.7, above, ] (D1) {\large{$d_{1}$}};
    
    \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.2mm] (R1.east) -- (N5.west) node[midway, above, ] (D4) {\large{$d_{4}$}};
    \path[] (D1) -- (D3) node[pos=0.85, scale=1.3] {$\vdots$};
    
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


